# exec command and non-root user

Tags: php, exec

I want to execute a command in PHP using `exec()` in my script like so but it is not working:

`exec('/bin:/usr/bin/php -f /home/myname/public_html/sample_script.php | at now');`

I have error reporting on and nothing reports an error. I am allowed to use the `exec()` function.

I ran the following command in SSH as root and it worked fine:

`php -f /home/myname/public_html/sample_script.php | at now`

I am on a VPS hosting plan.

My script is owned by `myname` and not root. Could that be why the `exec()` line is not working in the script?

If you need any more information, please ask.

Comment: Do you need the `/bin:` right at the start of the command line?

Comment: It's just the full path that my server told me. If I remove the `/bin:`, there is no difference.

Comment: Does the command run properly when you use the path from the command line? Can you run simpler commands - `touch /home/myname/public_html/sample` or something?

Comment: When I do something simple like
`exec('who', $result);
var_dump($result);`
`exec()` works fine.

When I change `/bin:/usr/bin/php` to `php`, there is no difference.

Comment: Sorry, it's just the `/bin:` part you don't need; `/usr/bin/php/` is fine. Can you also try putting together a very simple php script, and see if you can `exec()` that? I assume it's a file permission issue somewhere....

Comment: Hi. I made a very simple script, just a simple echo statement, and no change. Should I change the ownership of the script with the `exec()` function to `root` or would that be unsafe and would that even fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the 'at' command I added `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to the sudoers file. I also changed the exec call to `exec('echo /usr/bin/php -f /home/myname/public_html/sample_script.php | sudo /usr/bin/at now')`.